# Load more/Lazy load effect for FAQ custom posts

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created a custom post type of FAQ's with following fields -Ques, askedBy, hisPhoto, Answer, answeredBy, photo. I am able to display all faqs on front-page.php as-

```
<?php     $args = array('post_type' => 'faq');
          $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($the_query->have_posts()) :                     
            $color_counter=1; //if counter is odd then set faq div bkgcolor=cyan else bkgcolor=blue
            $color; 

        ?>                  
            <!-- Loop through the posts -->
            <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); 
                if ($color_counter % 2 == 0) : $color="ques-drk-blue"; 
                else:  $color="ques-cyan-blue"; 
                endif;
            ?>
                <div class="<?php echo $color ?>">
                     <div class="quote-wrapper"><blockquote><?php the_field('question'); ?></blockquote></div>
                     <div class="person-descr">
                            <?php $cust_img = get_field('cust_photo'); 
                                  if( !empty($cust_img) ): ?>                                        
                                     <div class="round-image" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $cust_img['url']; ?>);"></div>
                            <?php endif; ?> 
                            <div class="person"><?php the_field('cust_name'); ?></div>
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                     <div class="person-descr">
                            <?php $opti_img = get_field('optician_photo'); 
                                  if( !empty($opti_img) ): ?>                                        
                                     <div class="round-image" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $opti_img['url']; ?>);"></div>
                            <?php endif; ?> 
                            <br/><div class="person"><?php the_field('optician_name'); ?></div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="quote-wrapper"><blockquote><?php the_field('answer'); ?></blockquote></div>
                  </div>                    
            <?php $color_counter++ ;
                  endwhile;                   
                  wp_reset_postdata();              
            ?>
```

This displays all FAQ custom posts one after the other with the desired styling. But there could be lots of faqs, so I would like to achieve the lazy load or load more effect to it by initially displaying only 2 faqs and load more as user scrolled the page. 
Can such an effect be achieved if my query (WP_Query) is pre-fetching all faqs ? Please advice. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Here is the link where you can download complete working example with sample database.
```

In My example I am retrieving the posts from wordpress database and displaying 5 post on load,then each time when you scroll I am appending 5more posts to the same page.

[DEMO](https://github.com/silpareddy/Auto-Load-Posts)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. There was a slight error (incorrect table names) in your code. Just fixed that and i am seeing the results. I am new to jquery so trying to understand your code and playing around with it. I think this is closest to what I am looking for. will get back soon

Comment: Thank you Mansi, Let me know If you want more help to solve this issue.

Comment: I understand your code now. Thank you for posting it. I am having a challenge in integrating it into my wordpress site. for instance, querying custom posts is not as straightforward as querying normal posts etc. But thanks anyways. your code was helpful in understanding how Ajax works in general.

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely a few ways you could attack this problem.

Here is my suggestion. I am going to abstract away from specific code for now to see if it sounds like what you are looking for.

1. Store ALL FAQ data in a JS Array:

Since it sounds like it may be more performant to fetch for ALL FAQ data on page load, opposed to only querying for N posts at a time (5, 10, etc) when you need them, let's assume you make this initial call and store all FAQ data in a JS array. Think `data = JSON.parse( JSON_encoded(PHP_Array));`

2. Write a JS function that on callback from the data fetch, iterates over the array of FAQ's and appends the first X to your document, leaving the rest untouched in this global JS variable.

In your HTML you would display the first X FAQ's on the page, and track the index of the last FAQ being displayed on the page.

3. When the user scrolls/triggers the event to load more posts, the JS function run above would run again, but this time appending the next X FAQ's.

You would bind a JavaScript event listener to the window.scroll event. If the user's scroll position either reached the bottom of the page or brought an element placed below your current FAQ's into view, you would simply append another X FAQs onto your current list.

What do you think?

Comment: Thank you for your input. Theoretically I understand what you are saying but I am not able to implement it. I think I some help there. This is my first project with Wordpress and JQuery and this doesn't seem like a beginner level issue. I am still trying to figure out which WP files do what and where my code goes. Currently the code is all php. Do I need to write it in jquery instead and incorporate the js index part ?